# Format to use Exists Condition in MSBuild props file

Tags: msbuild, conditional-statements, prop

I need to check whether the given folder is available in the given path or not. If that folder is not available in the given path,then it has to take alternative folder mentioned.

So to check the existence of the given folder, i tried

I got error as  error MSB4092: An unexpected token "$(D:\DK)" was found at character position 11 in condition "'(Exists('$(D:\DK)')' "

What is the correct format to use this Exists condition?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite basic though it can be confusing apparently..
`$(<name>)` is used to refer to the property named `<name>` but you don't seem to have a property, just a string.
So either

```
<Message Condition="Exists('d:\dk')" Text="It Exists" />
```

or

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Dk>d:\dk</Dk>
</PropertyGroup>

<Message Condition="Exists($(Dk))" Text="It Exists" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the Exists condition with the following scenario and it works fine for me.

```
   <ROOT Condition="Exists('D:\DK')">D:\DK</ROOT>
   <ROOT Condition="'$(ROOT)'==''">D:\New\DK</ROOT>
```